# How to translate a custom Constraint message?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a [custom constraint](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/onlyone/tree/src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/LockedLanguagesConstraint.php) in the [Allow a content type only once (Only One)](https://www.drupal.org/project/onlyone) module that is working and is defined as:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\onlyone\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Checks that Only One node of locked languages exists.
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "LockedLanguages",
 *   label = @Translation("Locked Languages Constraint", context = "Validation"),
 *   type = { "entity" }
 * )
 */
class LockedLanguagesConstraint extends Constraint {

  /**
   * Message shown when a node of a locked language exists on a content type.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  public $nodeExists = "The content type %content_type is configured to have Only One node per language but the node <a href=':href'>@title</a> exists for the %language language.";

}
```

And I want to be able to translate the message, the problem is that you can't use the `t()` function in the property definition. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constraint system is one of the few places where string literals aren't directly wrapped in `t()`. One reason for this is probably because the variables which form the "context" and string replacements for the messages aren't directly available when defining the constraint. @see `\Drupal\Core\Validation\DrupalTranslator`.

So the answer is: core does this for you. You can see exactly where this happens in: `\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Validation\ExecutionContext::addViolation`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that I can't see my string to translate it from the /admin/config/regional/translate even if I see printed my message.

Comment: I believe these strings are scraped from the codebase and fed into localize.drupal.org to be translated. Not sure how this works though, maybe we could open an issue to explicitly scrape constraint messages.. in whatever project does that job.

Comment: Here is what I could find: (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/translation-api/overview): "Note: Translatable string extraction relies on the translation method names being t() and formatPlural()! For example, this will not work: ... because the translatable string extractor on https://localize.drupal.org/ will only find your translatable strings based on the known patterns of t() and formatPlural().". This lead to the following project: https://www.drupal.org/project/potx. So an issue in that queue to add more intelligent support to potx would probably make these strings appear.

Comment: And it looks like someone beat you to it: https://www.drupal.org/project/potx/issues/2884361 :)

Comment: Well the mistery was solved in slack, see my answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260311/28275

Comment: Interesting! TIL a lot about translations.

Answer (score 3):

The mystery is solved thanks to @dawehner on Slack.

Drupal handle this, in my case the problem was simple as see the site in another language and trigger the error, maybe I was a little tired to think in this possibility :-)

Comment: So you were able to add the translation at `/admin/config/regional/translate` ?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes.

Comment: I see now, in `/admin/config/regional/translate` new string won't show up until you switch/try to see it in another language. Which explains why `Select a forum.` did not show up.

Comment: @NoSssweat yes that's the point, but there is really a bug with potx project as it should extract this strings from core, leaving this method of switching language and trigger the errors only for the custom modules. Read more at https://www.drupal.org/project/potx/issues/2884361

Answer (score 1):

You're right, can't access the `t()` here.

Looking at an example from core:

*/core/modules/forum/src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/ForumLeafConstraint.php*

```
class ForumLeafConstraint extends Constraint {

  public $selectForum = 'Select a forum.';
  public $noLeafMessage = 'The item %forum is a forum container, not a forum. Select one of the forums below instead.';

}
```

In */admin/config/regional/translate* I was able to find the `$noLeafMessage` was translated:

[image]

But nothing for `$selectForum`

[image]

This makes me believe that the only way is to add it directly to a .po file and then import at */admin/config/regional/translate/import*

#### UPDATE:

If it's new, turns out the string will not show up for translation until you switch to another language. Which explains why `$selectForum` was not showing up.

Comment: I have the same behavior.

Comment: I think that the translated constraints comes from the tests that used the same string with the t() function to validate the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Add the string translation trait to your class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\onlyone\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Checks that Only One node of locked languages exists.
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "LockedLanguages",
 *   label = @Translation("Locked Languages Constraint", context = "Validation"),
 *   type = { "entity" }
 * )
 */
class LockedLanguagesConstraint extends Constraint {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * Message shown when a node of a locked language exists on a content type.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  public $nodeExists;

  // Set the value of $nodeExists somewhere in your code

}
```

Also see this note from the string translation trait:

```
   * If the class is capable of injecting services from the container, it should
   * inject the 'string_translation' service and assign it to
   * $this->stringTranslation.
```

Which means you should implement ContainerInjectionInterface and have create and __construct functions to do that injection, like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\onlyone\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Checks that Only One node of locked languages exists.
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "LockedLanguages",
 *   label = @Translation("Locked Languages Constraint", context = "Validation"),
 *   type = { "entity" }
 * )
 */
class LockedLanguagesConstraint extends Constraint implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The string translation service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationInterface
   */
  protected $stringTranslation;

  /**
   * Message shown when a node of a locked language exists on a content type.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  public $nodeExists;

  public function __construct($options = NULL, TranslationInterface $string_translation) {
    parent::__construct($options);
    $this->stringTranslation = $string_translation;

    // You can set the value of $nodeExists here if you want.
    $this->nodeExists = $this->t("The content type %content_type is configured to have Only One node per language but the node <a href=':href'>@title</a> exists for the %language language.");
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('string_translation')
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Have just read Sam's answer. If that's the case then none of this will help.

Comment: You can't do this: public $nodeExists = $this->t(""); defining a property. You can't use functions for this.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I wasn't looking at that part, fixing it.